# PHP Session Values

Tags: php, session, centos

I've configured session values in php.ini, for example `session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400`, but the changes don't take effect after restarting apache, as shown in the images:

[image: php.ini]
[image: phpinfo]

Comment: No .htaccess floating about? Its a setting that could exist in a .htaccess file (for some reason or other).

Comment: Are you sure you have edited the correct php.ini file? Sometimes there can be multiples of these. Does the value in your phpinfo() for `Loaded Configuration File` match the php.ini file that you edited?

Comment: It shows:

Loaded Configuration File /etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php.d

Is the file that I´m editing.... And exists a HTACCES outside the directort but it only has rewrite rules redirections

Comment: I'm doubtful the 'syntax error answer' in that duplicate linked question is the solution here.

Comment: IncredibleHat, you were right, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the default ttl of the sessions directly in your script:

```
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", 86400); 
session_start();
```

But as [noticed in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime), you must take in account that:

> If different scripts have different values of session.gc_maxlifetime but share the same place for storing the session data then **the script with the minimum value will be cleaning the data**. In this case, use this directive together with [session.save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path).

Then you should digg around [session.save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) too.